# Удаление строки из файла

Tags: файлы, c++

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать функцию удаления нужной строки из файла. Только не по номеру, а по содержимому! Я так предполагаю, что для начала нужно найти эту строку в файле! Функцию поиска по ключу я сделал:

```
bool findInSortList(FILE *&f,int St, string key, int &pp, int &wp, TEdaF &eda){
        if (St==-1) {
            cout<<"Список пустой"<<endl<<endl;
            return 0;
        };
        wp=St;
        while (wp != -1) {
        fseek(f,wp,SEEK_SET);
        fread(&eda,sizeof(TEdaF),1,f);
        if (key==eda.blud)
        {break;}
        else{
            pp=wp;
            wp=eda.Next;
        }
    }
if(wp!=-1 && eda.blud==key)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
```

Подскажите как дальше быть! Что делать? Ведь насколько я понимаю, то удалить из файла напрямую нельзя, ведь это не БД!

Comment: > Ведь насколько я понимаю, то удалить из файла напрямую нельзя, ведь это не БД!

 1. Читается весь файл целиком
 2. Находятся нужные строки
 3. Формируется новый текст без этих строк
 4. Пишется целиком в файл (заново)

Comment: Совершенно верно. Никто такую функциональность не представляет, всё делается руками.

И да, в C++ используйте fstream и readline.

Comment: Надеюсь `eda.blud` это `char[]`, а не `char *` или  `string`.

@Юра1996, насколько я вижу у Вас файл состоит из записей фиксированной длины. Иногда в таких файлах удаляемые записи просто помечают удаленными по месту.

А время от времени выполняют процедуру реального удаления (перезапись).

Естественно, это зависит от инструментов (и алгоритмов), котторые Вы используете для работы с файлом.

Comment: @Fike, а как изъять эту строку из всего текста?

Comment: @avp, да, eda.blud это char[]! Подскажите пожалуйста, как изъять нужную строку?